# how to implement multithreading to query sharded table in loop in php?

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, parallel-processing, sharding

//query to get all users from one table in one process and it should not take more then 30 seconds i also hase to queries inside loop to get additional data of users from different tables.

```
for($shard_id = $start_index; $shard_id <= $end_index; $shard_id++) {
            list($db, $sharded_table) = DbConfig::getInstance()
                ->getConnectionByShardId($shard_id, $shard_table);
            $query = "SELECT user_id,login_id,
                  first_name, middle_name, last_name, gender,
                  title,profile_image_url,
                  registered_user_type,properties
               FROM $sharded_table WHERE $where_clause";
            $st = $db->prepare($query);
            $ret = $st->execute();
            $data = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($data as $d){
                $rawData[] = $d;
            }
        }


// now i want to iterate each user to get additional properties from different tables containing user Ids
foreach($dataSet as $user){
    $temp = array();
    $properties = json_decode($user['properties'], true);
    $temp['first_name'] = CommonUtil::fetch($user,'first_name','');
    $temp['middle_name'] = CommonUtil::fetch($user, 'middle_name', '');
    $temp['last_name'] = CommonUtil::fetch($user, 'last_name', '');

    $temp['login_id'] = CommonUtil::fetch($user,'login_id','');
    $temp['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];
    $temp['enroll_grade'] = isset($properties['enroll_grade']) && !empty($properties['enroll_grade']) ? $properties['enroll_grade'] : "-";
    $temp['session'] = isset`enter code here`($properties['session']) && !empty($properties['session']) ? $properties['session'] : "2012-2013";
    $temp['admission_session'] = isset($properties['admission_session']) && !empty($properties['admission_session']) ? $properties['admission_session'] : "2012-2013";
    $userRelationShip =getUserRelationships($user['user_id']);
    if(!empty($userRelationShip)){
        $userRelationShips[]=$user['user_id'];
    }
    $temp['user_relationship']=json_encode($userRelationShip);
    $userProperties=getUserProperties($user['user_id']);
    $temp['user_relationship']=json_encode($userProperties);
    $userTemp[]=$temp;
}
```

//the whole process is taking lot of time to prepare whole data . intent is to insert it inside mongoDb to make execution fast

```
CREATE TABLE `user_profiles` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'first name',
  `middle_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'middle name',
  `last_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'last name',
  `login_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'globally unique email address or name',
  `password_hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'encrypted password',
  `gender` enum('male','female') DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'gender of the user (male or female)',
  `title` enum('mr','ms','mrs','dr') DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'title of the user (mr, ms, mrs, dr etc)',
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date of Birth',
  `secret_code` varchar(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'secret code used to connect users',
  `default_calendar_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'default calendar id',
  `default_folder_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'default folder id',
  `default_album_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'default album id',
  `profile_album_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'profile album id',
  `profile_photo_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'profile photo id as stored in the profile album',
  `profile_image_url` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user profile image url',
  `registered_user_type` enum('teacher','parent','student') DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'registered user type as',
  `referrer_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user who referred the current user to BY',
  `notification_preference` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'notification preference, JSON array of various notifications that the current user is configured to be notified',
  `privacy_preference` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'privacy preference, JSON array of various privacy preferences that the current user has configured',
  `properties` varchar(8192) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user specific properties, JSON name-value pairs used to manage user experience etc',
  `app_properties` varchar(8192) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'application user properties',
  `phone_info` varchar(2048) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'phone information JSON array of (number, provider, activation_code, verified_ts). The first number is primary contact.',
  `phone_info_updated_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'last phone info updated timestamp',
  `notification_preference_updated_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'last notification preference updated timestamp',
  `privacy_preference_updated_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'last privacy preference updated timestamp',
  `password_updated_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'last password updated timestamp',
  `profile_updated_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'last profile updated timestamp',
  `secret_code_updated_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'last secret code updated timestamp',
  `status` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending' COMMENT 'user status - ''pending'',''active'',''deleted''',
  `created_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'created timestamp of the user',
  `approved_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'approved timestamp of the user',
  `updated_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'row updated timestamp',
  `school_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'School Id for the relavent user',
  `organization_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Organization Id for the relavent school',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `status_index` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='a BY user profile' |
```

Comment: however you do it, beware of your line where you replace user_relationship array entry with `$userProperties`.

Comment: Back up -- What is the real problem?  Something is not running "fast enough"?  What?  There probably is a way to speed things up that has nothing to do with multi-threading or sharding.

Comment: How big is the table?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: How many machines is this "sharded" across?  (Or are you sharding across some other set of things?)  I am confused by `$shard_table` vs simply `user_profiles`.  The table does not seem to be sharded?  Oh, maybe you are mis-using the term "shard"?

Comment: this is just an example shard table name calculated run time let say user_profile_1,user_profile_2,user_profile_3 etc shard id depends on shard key lets say if table is sharded by user_id so algorithm takes modulus of shard id and insert the data into it.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not support multithreading so you won't be able to achieve what you want to do (unless you want to experiment with [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) but I would not recommend).

To speed up the process though, you can insert a caching layer to avoid querying data from the DB directly. That seems like the most robust and scalable way to improve your performance.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry I didn't get the point :-( It seems too complex to me, specially the for loop where you have a SELECT stmt, I'm afraid this is the main cause for your "the whole process is taking lot of time to prepare whole data". Try executing this query once. Good luck!

Comment: actually i want to import all data  into mongoDB thats the need.

Comment: but i have to do it to extract all the data in all sharded tables containing user information and insert it into mongoDB.